# Setting javaagent in Play framework 2.5.x

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5

I am trying to hunt down memory issues, so I would like to use for example [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm/) to inspect sizes of my data structures, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

In my build.sbt I add:

```
javaOptions += "-javaagent:jamm-0.3.1.jar"
packageOptions ++= Seq(Package.ManifestAttributes("Premain-Class" -> "org.github.jamm.MemoryMeter"),
                       Package.ManifestAttributes("Agent-Class" -> "org.github.jamm.MemoryMeter"))
libraryDependencies += "com.github.jbellis" % "jamm" % "0.3.1"
```

I have tried this and other variants like `sbt run -J-javaagent:jamm-0.3.1.jar` but I always get exception that instrumentation has not been set in jamm:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Instrumentation is not set; Jamm must be set as -javaagent
              at org.github.jamm.MemoryMeter.measure(MemoryMeter.java:210)
              ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only talk about my experience with the New Relic Java agent, which I used in my play app in production mode.

You should be able to include the agent with something like this:

```
activator run -J-javaagent:/temp/jamm-0.3.1.jar
```

The jamm jar should be somewhere on your filesystem and the full path should be set on the -javaagent option.